# Show/Hide content based on button answer

Tags: javascript, toggle

I'm trying to make my code show/hide blocks of code based on a button selection. I am very much a beginner with JavaScript. I know almost nothing about how to make it work and this is my first attempt at writing it and as expected, I failed horribly. But hopefully, you can figure out what I'm trying to do.

The HTML:

```
<p>Do you want to go for a swim?</p>
<button onclick="#option1-yes" class="option1yes">Yes</button> <button onclick="#option1-no" class="option1no">No</button>

<p id="option1-yes">Let's go to the water park! There's a water park around the corner from you.</p><button onclick="#option2-yes">Sounds Fun</button> <button onclick="#option2-no">I want to do something else</button>

<p id="option1-no">Let's go to the mall! There's a mall 15 miles away from you.</p>
<button onclick="#option3-yes">Sounds Fun</button> <button onclick="#option3-no">I want to do something else</button>
```

My sad attempt at JavaScript:

```
var displayOption = function toggleOption() {
  var option1 = document.getElementByClass('option1yes')

  var option2 = document.getElementByClass('option1no')

  if (.click('.option1yes')) {
    option2.style.display = 'none'
  }
  else option1.style.display = 'block'
}
```

**EDIT:** I'm trying to get the first question to display, then when the user answers the first question, make the second or third question show up depending on what the previous answer was.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

So, there's a bit that I would like to address and if I am leading you down the wrong path, please let me know and I'll update my answer.

1) in HTML the `onclick` attribute for a button is traditionally used to call some JavaScript function... `onclick="test()"` would call `function test(){...}` in your JS.  Using the hash-ID does not really accomplish anything here (in anchor tags, the href attribute + hash-ID lets the browser jump to a section in a page `<a href="#content-section">`)

2) Your function declaration `var displayOption = function toggleOption()` may be valid, but it's unclear on how to read (for me at least).  What is your function name? toggleOption() displayOption()?

2b) Additionally, there is nothing calling your function to actually kick things off.  You have all your code wrapped in displayOption() but there's nothing invoking that to trigger your nested code.

3) `.click()` in traditional JavaScript is just used as a method to invoke the click action -- it is not a true/false test.  If you did `option1.click()` that would programmatically click your option1 element like a mouse click)

3b) To listen for a click event, my favorite approach is `element.addEventListener('click', function(){ .. } )` -- this will set your JavaScript to listen if/when that specific element button is clicked, and then execute code accordingly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

4) To my knowledge there is no `.getElementByClass()` -- there is, however, a `.getElementsByClassName()` which it's important to note it will return a node**list** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName

4b) Since you are targeting specific elements, you can assign them IDs and then use `.getElementById()` to connect them to your JavaScript 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
which will only return the first matched result.

```js
var option1yes = document.getElementById('option1yes')
var option1no  = document.getElementById('option1no')

option1yes.addEventListener('click', function(){
    option1no.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<p>Do you want to go for a swim?</p>
<button id="option1yes">Yes</button> 
<button id="option1no">No</button>

<p>Let's go to the water park! There's a water park around the corner from you.</p>
<button id="option2-yes">Sounds Fun</button> 
<button id="option2-no">I want to do something else</button>

<p>Let's go to the mall! There's a mall 15 miles away from you.</p>
<button id="option3-yes">Sounds Fun</button> 
<button id="option3-no">I want to do something else</button>
```

---

### UPDATE

Ok, to hide and show sections of a web page, there's a couple of first steps to build upon from the previous points here :)

1) You will need to isolate the sections you want to hide/show in their own containers -- commonly developers use `div`s for this.

1b) in this example, I put the subsequent questions inside of `div`s and gave them both a unique ID so that we can target them easier in the JavaScript.  They also have the same CSS class `.hidden` which is discussed in point #2 :)

2) Your sections should start hidden, this can be done with some CSS

2b) in this example, I created a CSS class named `.hidden` by adding it to an element, the CSS value for it will be set to `display: hidden;` (by taking it off, via JavaScript, the element will revert back to its default display value)

2c) you can use `element.className=""` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className or `element.classList` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList -- I like `.className` but that's just what I'm used to.

3) To make sure users can change choices, the JavaScript removes the `.hidden` class from it's intended target but adds it back to the other div section(s) that needs to be hidden.

```js
var btnYes = document.getElementById('option1yes');
var btnNo  = document.getElementById('option1no');
var optYes = document.getElementById('option1-yes');
var optNo  = document.getElementById('option1-no');

btnYes.addEventListener('click', function(){
  optYes.className = ''; 
  optNo.className = 'hidden';
});

btnNo.addEventListener('click', function(){
  optNo.className = '';
  optYes.className = 'hidden';
});
```

```css
.hidden{ display: none; }
```

```html
<p>Do you want to go for a swim?</p>
<button id="option1yes">Yes</button> 
<button id="option1no">No</button>

<div id="option1-yes" class="hidden">
  <p>Let's go to the water park! There's a water park around the corner from you.</p>
  <button id="option2yes">Sounds Fun</button> 
  <button id="option2no">I want to do something else</button>
</div>

<div id="option1-no" class="hidden">
  <p>Let's go to the mall! There's a mall 15 miles away from you.</p>
  <button id="option3yes">Sounds Fun</button> 
  <button id="option3no">I want to do something else</button>
</div>
```

Comment: OHH, I see what you mean. Thank you so much, this extremely helpful!!! I was aiming for something a little different though. I want to hide the other questions and when the user clicks yes or no, then show the second question.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! This is so helpful you; you have no idea!!!!! I have one last question but if it's too complicated or if you don't want to answer it, don't worry about it; you've already been so helpful!!!

Is there a way to make the first question disappear after the button has been clicked, so the second question is the only thing on the screen?

Comment: Yep! you would put the first question in its own div with a unique ID -- and in the addEventListener functions, add the 'hidden' class to that div wrapping your first question.

Answer (score 0):

when you show one element you should hide the other, so you can insert an id in each element, hide the elements at the beginning. So, as you have an id you can create an onclick function and and do whatever you want, for example:

HTML

```
<p>Do you want to go for a swim?</p>
<button id="option1yes">Yes</button>
<button id="option1no">No</button>
<p id="option1-yes">Let's go to the water park! There's a water park around the corner from you.</p>
<p id="option1-no">Let's go to the mall! There's a mall 15 miles away from you.</p>
```

Javascript

```
var y = document.getElementById("option1-yes");
var n = document.getElementById("option1-no");
y.style.display = "none";
n.style.display = "none";

document.getElementById("option1yes").onclick = function () {
    y.style.display = "block";
    n.style.display = "none";
};

document.getElementById("option1no").onclick = function () {
    y.style.display = "none";
  n.style.display = "block";
};
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lima21/vg19sj2p/)